NGINX multiple authentication methods (one or the other) AND an IP check seems impossible
location / {
        proxy_pass $forward_auth_target;

        allow xxxxx/24;
        deny all;

        satisfy any; # This gets satisfied by the IP check, and auth is completely bypassed

        auth_basic "xxxx";
        auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/basic_auth/$forward_auth_bypass";

        auth_request     /outpost.goauthentik.io/auth/nginx;
        error_page       401 = @goauthentik_proxy_signin;

        auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
        add_header       Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-username $authentik_username;

        auth_request_set $authentik_username $upstream_http_x_authentik_username;
        auth_request_set $authentik_groups $upstream_http_x_authentik_groups;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-groups $authentik_groups;

        auth_request_set $authentik_email $upstream_http_x_authentik_email;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-email $authentik_email;

        auth_request_set $authentik_name $upstream_http_x_authentik_name;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-name $authentik_name;

        auth_request_set $authentik_uid $upstream_http_x_authentik_uid;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-uid $authentik_uid;

        auth_request_set $authentik_uid $upstream_http_x_authentik_uid;
        proxy_set_header X-authentik-uid $authentik_uid;

        auth_request_set $authentik_auth $upstream_http_authorization;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $authentik_auth;
}

location /outpost.goauthentik.io {
        proxy_pass              http://xxxx/outpost.goauthentik.io;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
        add_header              Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
        auth_request_set        $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
}

location @goauthentik_proxy_signin {
        internal;
        add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
        return 302 /outpost.goauthentik.io/start?rd=$request_uri;
}

The goal is to bypass SSO if a correct HTTP Basic Auth header is present while making sure connections are only from said IPs.
When I disable the IP check it works flawlessly. How could I separate these?

"satisfy any" is happy whenever the access module is happy, there is no way around that I know.
I see your upstream is already variable, but I would set it with a geo to replace the allow/deny. I think this works even if it's variable from another map. If not you will need to combine the geo with another map.
geo $upstreamphttps {
 default alwaysdownupstream;
xxxxx/24 $forward_auth_target;

}

I'm usually lazy and set the upstream perma down, but you could make a proper local block page if you prefer to throw a 403 instead of a 504.
upstream alwaysdownupstream {
server localhost down;
}

